# reference for contraction mapping conditions

Tags: reference-request, contraction-mapping

Looking for a reference for a textbook that discusses classical conditions for contraction mapping, such as diagonal dominance. It should contain theorems similar to the one in the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yURY0.png) (which I found on [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2319134/derivative-based-sufficient-conditions-for-contraction-mappings-for-multivariate) post without a source).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hope it is better now